# XML Unmarshalling in Go gives empty result with exported fields

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I am getting an empty result when doing XML unmarshall in Go. I have researched other SO questions and I have noticed that the most common reason for this seems to be that the fields are not exported. This is not true in my case, since all the names begin with an uppercase letter.

The xml looks like this (with nearly 1.000.000 `ROW` tags inside one single `ROWDATA`):

```
<ROWDATA>
<ROW>
  <ПІБ>    ПОПКО    РУСЛАН ВАСИЛЬОВИЧ</ПІБ>
  <Місце_проживання>61112, Харківська обл., місто Харків, Московський район, ПРОСПЕКТ П'ЯТДЕСЯТИРІЧЧЯ ВЛКСМ, будинок 86, квартира 65</Місце_проживання>
  <Основний_вид_діяльності>45.32 Роздрібна торгівля деталями та приладдям для автотранспортних засобів</Основний_вид_діяльності>
  <Стан>зареєстровано</Стан>
</ROW>
</ROWDATA>
```

And this is what I have done:

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Rowdata struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ROWDATA"`
    Rowdata []Row    `xml:"ROW"`
}

type Row struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"ROW"`
    Location string   `xml:"Місце_проживання"`
    Director string   `xml:"ПІБ"`
    Activity string   `xml:"Основний_вид_діяльності"`
    City     string   `xml:"Стан"`
}

func main() {

    xmlFile, err := os.Open("FOP_1.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer xmlFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    koi8rString := transform.NewReader(strings.NewReader(string(byteValue)), charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder())

    decBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(koi8rString)

    var entries Rowdata

    xml.Unmarshal(decBytes, &entries)

    for i := 0; i < len(entries.Rowdata); i++ {
        fmt.Println("Name: " + entries.Rowdata[i].Director)
    }
}
```

And the last for loop never runs, because the length is zero. However, I have a similar example where the file was already UTF8, so no encoding transformation was needed, and it went well. I wonder if I messed up something while decoding?

UPDATE: I tested a simpler version with a string rather than a file in the [Go Play Space](https://goplay.space/#6RDPB8S6a4l), and it works fine! However, my local version with the file still doesn't work, so I suspect it might have something to do with the actual reading of the file...

UPDATE2: I just realized that `xml.Unmarshall` returns:

`xml: encoding "windows-1251" declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil%`

That might be the cause of this... but what does it mean?

Comment: It is not directly playable through Go-playgrund. So, is `decBytes` also empty when you run your code?

Comment: No, decBytes prints out the full xml file with correct encoding. Sorry, edit, the file is printed if I transform it to string, but yes, decBytes is the correct byte representation of the file.

Comment: `xml.Unmarshal` returns an error. Please check the error and paste it here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @leafbebop , I have edited to add the error message. I think that thanks to your suggestion, this is going in the right direction...

Comment: I think that somewhere in your xml file there is a declaration saying the file is in `win-1251` encoding. Though you transform it into utf-8, the declaration is not removed thus making the parser think you shall provide a `CharsetReader`. And I would suggest instead of the transform, do provide a `CharsetReader` like the code @ain provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you have "nearly 1.000.000 ROW tags" and in your code you use `ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)` to read it all into memory (twice!) - thats totally unnessesary and you might run out of memory. Instead of reading it into memory you should use "streaming" decoder, something like

```
import "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("FOP_1.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    parser := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
    parser.CharsetReader = charset.NewReaderLabel

    for {
        t, _ := parser.Token()
        if t == nil {
            break
        }

        switch se := t.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            if se.Name.Local == "ROW" {
                var item Row
                parser.DecodeElement(&item, &se)
                fmt.Println("Name: " + item.Director)
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. I've got another UTF8 file of same size, and sure, the speed was overall much slower and the process much clunkier than the streaming option you suggest here.  However, I am still wondering if the "all at once" approach with unmarshalling could still work for a non UTF8 file. I tried to create  a `CharsetReader`, but `Unmarshall` expects a byte slice, so I am not sure how to proceed. Anyways, at least I've got your streaming solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"

decoder := xml.NewDecoder(file)
decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReaderLabel

err := decoder.Decode(&temp)
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**